# If in Pete's World there's no Doctor, how is there a Torchwood?

Tags: doctor-who

Torchwood was founded because of The Doctor's interference with the Queen with the werewolf.

But in Pete's world, there is no Doctor.  How is there still a Torchwood in this world if there is no Doctor?

Comment: Maybe the werewolf incident itself prompted the Queen to found Torchwood. Of course, that doesn't explain how the werewolf was handled *without* the Doctor.

Comment: Timey wimey wibbly wobbly.

Comment: More importantly, how could the organisation or the estate in Scotland possibly be called "Torchwood" since there's no "Doctor Who" for it to be an anagram of? ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### There is no reason an institute such as Torchwood would be dependent on any single event to precipitate its existence. Since this is a parallel reality, it stands to reason, another event or even an entirely different person may have triggered the existence of Pete's Torchwood.

- **For all we know, the queen was indeed killed at Torchwood. This may have been the event needed to create Torchwood in Pete's World in her memory. There was such a stockpile of scientific and occult knowledge at the site already, it would have been a fitting site given the significance of the Queen's death.**
- Given the events of the episode, had the Doctor not been there, it is unlikely the queen would have survived. It was the Doctor who noticed at dinner something was amiss. It was the Doctor who figured out the house was a trap and it was the Doctor who put together the significance of the house, the NOT-A-Telescope in the observatory and the super-large diamond.
- If their world was anything like our Universe, there were plenty of extraterrestrial, supernatural or other-dimensional attempts which may have taken place and were successfully thwarted WITHOUT the intervention of a Time Lord, I might add.
- That universe's Humans were obviously quite capable and talented to have survived without the intervention of a Time Lord. Granted, many of the threats to Earth existed BECAUSE of the Doctor's presence there...so they may have had fewer such incursions to deal with.
- Our world history is rife with people having the same idea around the same time even while the two people were in completely different countries at the same time. Alexander Graham Bell and Elisha Grey were both working on the telephone at the same time. Bell simply managed to patent his earlier in the same day.

Comment: As we saw from "Turn left", many of the threats that the Doctor dealt with would have still been resolved, albeit with far greater loss of human life.

Comment: It's very possible that Torchwood was founded *because* that universe lacked the Doctor (well more generally a "protector of the Realm" if you will)

Comment: This country needs healing. This country needs medicine. In fact I'd go so far as to say, that what this country needs, right now, is a doctor...

Comment: And the queen's death could potentially explain the fact that the UK was run by a president, if it triggered some shift in political structure.

Answer (score 22):

The Torchwood Institute was founded by Queen Victoria after she encountered werewolf/aliens at the Torchwood Estate in Scotland. **It was the presence of "other-worldly" creatures that prompted the establishment, rather than the specific involvement of The Doctor.**

> **VICTORIA:** *I saw last night that Great Britain has enemies beyond imagination, and we must defend our borders on all sides. I propose an
>   Institute to investigate these strange happenings and to fight them. I
>   would call it Torchwood. The Torchwood Institute. And if this Doctor
>   should return, then he should beware, because Torchwood will be
>   waiting.* - <sub><sup>[Tooth and Claw](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/28-2.htm)</sup></sub>

As you've pointed out, there is no Doctor in the alternate reality known as Pete's World (Pete refers to him as Rose's "famous Doctor" in Doomsday), but it does still have many of the same characters and features as the prime universe. Had The Doctor not turned up to help Queen Victoria defend herself against the werewolf threat, it's certainly possible that they would have been defeated or evaded another way, rather than by fighting the beasts in the observatory.

Note that in the alternate universe (and in the absence of the Doctor) Reynolds would have stood as Victoria's protector. His plan was simply to run away. Who's to say that that plan wouldn't have worked just as well?

> **REYNOLDS:** *Then remove yourself, Ma'am. Doctor, you stand as Her Majesty's Protector. And you, Sir Robert, you're a traitor to the
>   crown.*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *Bullets can't stop it!*
>
> **REYNOLDS:** *They'll buy you time. **Now run!***
>
> [Library]
>
> (Reynolds empties his revolver at the werewolf before it pounces and
>   rips him apart.)
>
> **DOCTOR:** *Rose!*
>
> **ROBERT:** *Barricade the door.* <sub><sup>[Tooth and Claw](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/28-2.htm)</sup></sub>

As mentioned above, **the Torchwood institute wasn't set up in response to the Doctor's presence** but in response to the aliens threatening to turn the Queen into a willing puppet. That would presumably be true in either reality.